# Better cleaner way to add ID/Class to Rails link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

New-ish to Rails... I've created a helper to format race names & their dates. I need to pass `:id => "current-race"` if a condition is present (basically if event is happening now). How could I go about this?

```
def formatted_race_dates(race)
    link_to (race.homepage) do
      raw("<strong>#{race.name}</strong> <em>#{race_dates_as_string(race)}</em>")
    end
end
```

now when `race.start_date < Date.today && race.end_date > Date.today` I'd like to add `id="current-race"` to the link.

I would normally set up an if/else condition and format it two ways. But seems there must be a Ruby trick I don't know to simplify something as common adding of a id/class to one `link_to` in a list? Even without the condition I'm not quite sure where/how to add `:id => "current-race"`.

So many Ruby/Rails tricks I don't know...everything helps!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `link_to` method takes options for this very reason:

```
link_to(race.homepage, :id => 'current-race') do ...
```

You can even add conditions to trigger it selectively:

```
link_to(race.homepage, :id => (race.start_date < Date.today && race.end_date > Date.today) ? 'current-race' : nil) do ...
```

You can even collapse this if you have a method for Race that indicates if it's current:

```
link_to(race.homepage, :id => race.current? ? 'current-race' : nil) do ...
```

This is easily implemented in your model and can be used in other places:

```
def current?
  self.start_date < Date.today && self.end_date > Date.today
end
```

Having it in the model makes it significantly easier to test.

Comment: hmmm. just adding `:id => 'current-race'` (same as your first example) breaks app: `/app/helpers/races_helper.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
      link_to (race.homepage, :id => 'current-race') do`

Comment: hmm. `link_to (race.homepage, :id => ...` fails while `link_to(race.homepage, :id => ...` works. but `link_to (race.homepage)` works as well!?!  **One lousy space**. which would be expected in any other language. One of hardest parts of Ruby/Rails to me is the fact that it IS lenient...makes it *harder* to learn in my opinion. c'est la vie...

Comment: The Ruby parser can be confused about syntax in odd cases like the one you've exposed there. This mostly stems from the fact that it's very relaxed in most regards, as brackets are optional and in most other languages they are required. Good to hear that worked for you, though.